# Smooth transition triggered in .each() callback (D3)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've created a transition that's invoked in D3's `selection.each()`, but there is a slight delay between the callback and the transition. I'd like the transition to appear to be *continuous* rather than having a slight delay. I've tried playing with different duration and delay values but to no avail. Here is the relevant code.

```
transition();

function transition() {

    data.map( (d) => {
        d.x = d3.random.normal(d['x'], 5)();
        d.y = d3.random.normal(d['y'], 5)();
        return d;
    });

    g.selectAll('path')
        .data(data)
        .transition()
        .duration(400)
        .attr('d', (d, i) => line( getPath(d, i) ) )
        .each('end', transition);

}
```

As you can see in [this working codepen](http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/wKzELW), there is a slight delay between the transitions. I'd like the transition to appear to be continuous. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points...

1. The default easing in d3 transitions is not linear so that is why you perceive a delay.
2. You are actually setting a new transition after each individual path transition completes. The `each` method calls back for every node in the selection and there is no built-in endall event in d3 transitions but, [you can make one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/WC_7Xi6VV50/j1HK0vIWI-EJ) as shown below.

The first point is probably the most important.  The second point is just avoiding unnecessarily re-applying the transitions and interrupting the previously applied ones.  Probably not perceptible but good practice anyway.

Here is a working example...

```js
var colors = [
 '#FFAA5C',
 '#DA727E',
 '#AC6C82',
 '#685C79',
 '#455C7B'
]



var line = d3.svg.line()
 .x( (d) => d.x )
 .y( (d) => d.y )
 .interpolate('linear'); 

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');

var svgW = d3.select('svg').node().clientWidth;
var svgH = d3.select('svg').node().clientHeight;

var w = svgW/4;
var h = svgH/4;

var data = [  {x: -w/2, y: -h/4}, {x: 0, y: -h/2}, {x: w/2, y: -h/4}, 
        {x: w/Math.PI, y:h/2.5}, {x: -w/4, y: h/2.5} ];

var getPath = (d, i) => {
 var path = [];
 
 var startPoint = { x: 0, y: 0 };
 // point 1
 path.push(startPoint);

 // point 2
 path.push(d);
 
 // point 3
 path.push(data[i + 1] || data[0]);
 
 // point 4
 path.push(startPoint);
 
 return path;

}

var g = svg.append('g')
 .attr('transform', 'translate(' + svgW/2 + ',' + svgH/2 + ')');

g.selectAll('path')
 .data(data)
.enter().append('path')
 .attr({
  fill: (d, i) => colors[i]
 });

transition();

function transition() {
 
 data.map( (d) => {
  d.x = d3.random.normal(d['x'], 5)();
  d.y = d3.random.normal(d['y'], 5)();
  return d;
 });
 
 g.selectAll('path')
  .data(data)
  .transition()
  .ease("linear")
  .duration(50)
  .attr('d', (d, i) => line( getPath(d, i) ) )
  .call(endall, function(){window.requestAnimationFrame(transition)});
 
}

  function endall(transition, callback) { 
    if (transition.size() === 0) { callback() }
    var n = 0; 
    transition 
        .each(function() { ++n; }) 
        .each("end", function() { if (!--n) callback.apply(this, arguments); }); 
  }
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #181818;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
}

svg {
 overflow: visible;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Interesting implementation. Also, I totally thought linear was the default the default easing function. Thanks for the well thought out response.

Comment: Cheers @Himmel I was inspired by the design of your demo. Nice!